# cannot find file with file_exists

Tags: php

I am trying to look for a file called `test.txt` within the folder called `.test`.

```
<?php 
 $path = '/localhost/joshcms/.test/test.txt';
 $fileexists = file_exists($path);
 if ($fileexists == '1') {
  $result = 'true';
 } else {
   $result = 'false';
 }
?>
```

Please excuse the horrible formatting, I am creating this PHP within Jade.

I, first of all, had the `$path` variable set to `.test/test.txt` so when it searched for the file, it looked in: `localhost/joshcms/.test/test.txt` because it was a relative path; because that never worked, I then changed the code to look the way it is above and yet, it still does not work. I then tried with a file that was in the same folder and that worked fine.

I'm not too sure if this error is occurring due to me trying to find something in a hidden folder or if it's just the function doesn't work unless the file is in the same directory as the PHP script/file itself.

Comment: `if ($fileexists == '1')` remove the quotes, you're checking for a string rather than boolean, or use `true` with no quotes. Same goes for `'true'` and `'false'` unless you're wanting to use strings.

Comment: `file_exists()` returns bool(true|false). Checking the response against a string `1` like so `if ($fileexists == '1')` will not pass. Just use `if ($fileexists) {`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I was reading the W3Schools tutorial section on how to find files, where it says output, I assumed it meant it outputted it as a string. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_exists.asp

Comment: Plus, your path `'/localhost/joshcms/` that may not be what you need to use here, but more like `/var/usr/home/joshcms/` as an example.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php `bool file_exists ( string $filename )` - what W3 Schools fails to mention is that that function returns a boolean. Always refer to the official manual.

Comment: " I was reading the W3Schools" well there is your problem that site is shit, stick to the manaul

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Ahh yes, it's working now - thank you the help. I've been also been reading over the past while that W3Schools isn't the best place to learn, due to errors - now I know.

Comment: @JoshMurray seeing we're doing all the work here lol somebody else comes along and plops answers. They do it to use "every time". and you're welcome ;-)

Comment: @JoshMurray official manuals can be a bit difficult for some of the functions, yet they hold more water than most ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes, as a 16 year-old the PHP manuals can be a little tricky to understand... W3Schools is good for me because it dumbs it down into something I can understand - lol.

Comment: @JoshMurray Oh no doubt. I for one have actually first started learning from them (many moons ago) and I have no shame to say it. Yet, later on have referred to the official manuals. But... you know what? I still do occasionally go there. It's not perfect but they do have some good stuff on their site. People need to remember that it's a "school", and schools don't teach us all the trick of the trade, as it were ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) returns `bool(true|false)`, so checking the response against a string `'1'` like so `if ($fileexists == '1')` will not pass.

The following will work:

```
$path = '/localhost/joshcms/.test/test.txt';
if ( file_exists($path) ) { // returns bool(true|false) response
    $result = 'true'; // if file exists, this condition will satisfy as the file does exist bool(true)
} else {
   $result = 'false'; // if the file at $path does not exist, this will satisfy; bool(false)
}
```

Aside: `$result` will now, per your code, hold a *string* value of true/false. If you want `$result` to hold a *boolean* value of true/false, remove the single-quotes, ie. `$result = true;` and `$result = false;`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is just path-related. It has nothing to do with the dot in the Directory name. That, anyways, has other implications of its own that are not applicable in the current context. You could always use the __DIR_ _ Constant or the dirname( __FILE_ _)  Function and work your way up or down to the location of the File.

```
<?php
        $file1     = __DIR__ . "/.test/test.txt";     //THIS SCRIPT LIVES IN THE SAME DIRECTORY AS THE ".test" FOLDER           
        $file2     = __DIR__ . "/../.test/test.txt";  //THIS SCRIPT LIVES 1 DIRECTORY BELOW THE ".test" FOLDER

        if( file_exist($file1) ){
            var_dump("THE FILE: {$file1} EXISTS.");
        }else{
            var_dump("CANNOT FIND THE FILE: {$file1} EXISTS.");
        }
```